# How do I enable Qt text to speech module in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, text-to-speech, ubuntu-18.04

I am a trying to install Qt text speech module for an app, I got it working for windows and Mac Osx

For Linux I am getting this error

> $ qmake "CONFIG +=test"
>
> Project MESSAGE: Configuring test build...
>
> Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: texttospeech

```
/qt4/QtTest -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild/release/.moc -Ibuild/release/.ui -o build/release/.obj/olam.o src/olam.cpp

src/olam.cpp:10:10: fatal error: QTextToSpeech: No such file or directory

 #include <QTextToSpeech>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Other relevant information**

Os: Ubuntu Bionic

Qt version: 5.9

Failing test in CI: https://travis-ci.org/tachyons/olam/jobs/603473843

Comment: You state that you are using Qt 5.9 but the error message shows include directories to qt4.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint from MathiasSchimid. Issue was that build was taking qt4 libs instead of Qt5, Fixed by adding `qt5-default` package

> sudo apt-get install qt5-default